# ReactJs - trigger click on element with class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

This is generated element by the plugin

```
<span class="leaflet-draw-draw-polyline">...</span>
```

I want to click on an element from some other part of the code.

How can I trigger click on this element without using ref on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the element seems to be completely out of a React component's scope, you could try either of the following:

1. create a React component and use `ref`s
2. simply use `document.getElementsByClassName()` and [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: you just save my day! :)